# Uso de Ternario em function Map

Tags: javascript, typescript, algoritmo

Olá, estou com uma dificuldade de implementar a logica com uso de ternário com o uso de map. A ideia base é caso nao tenha nenhum valor em items que item fique com valor vazio, pois preciso receber o algum valor diferente de null.
Segue a implementação base:

```
    produtos: {
      items:
        f.lista.produtos.items.map(e => {
          const p = {
            quantity: e?.quantity? ?? null,
            value: e?.value ?? null,
          };
          return p;
        }),
    },
```

Tentei usando o ternario junto ao map,

```
    produtos: {
      items:
        f.lista.produtos.items ?? [].map(e => {
          const p = {
            quantity: e?.quantity? ?? null,
            value: e?.value ?? null,
          };
          return p;
        }),
    },
```

porem apareceu os seguintes erros :

> error TS1005: ':' expected.

E os demais campos ficaram  dentro de p com essa sinalização :

> Property 'quantity' does not exist on type 'never'

O items é um array de objetos , e por ser um array ele nao pode receber a propriedade null, e sim vazio. Isso esta sendo enviado para um producer do kafka. Os objetos dentro dele estao setados como possibilidade de valor null, menos o items por ser tratar de um array.

Sendo assim,qual sera a melhor solucao para que consiga retorna um array sem propriedade dentro "[]", ja que tenho que ter algo nesse envio, caso nao tenha valor a ser enviado ao map. Exemplo : Nao existe nem quantity nem value, pois items nao foi "gerado".

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Não está dando para entender a pergunta pois a descrição do problema não condiz com o código que está escrevendo. Seria bom [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um [mcve] onde tivesse uma amostra do array de entrada `f.lista.produtos.items` e um exemplo de como quer a saída. Uma observação quanto ao uso do [operador ternário condicional](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), sua sintaxe é `condição ? expr1 : expr2` e onde faz seu uso `e?.quantity? ?? null` está faltando `: expr2` avalia quando a condição é `false`.

Answer (score -3):

Colocar o items em uma variável fora do seu objeto produtos pode facilitar na visualização.

```
const items = f.lista.produtos.items.map(p => ({ 
    quantity: p?.quantity || null,
    value: p?.value || null
});


{
    produtos: { items: items?.length ? items : undefined, },
}
```

No caso do `produto.items` não existir aqui, o novo "produtos.items" vai ser `undefined`.

Se quiser colocar tudo no mesmo objeto:

```
{
    produtos: { 
        items: f.lista.produtos?.items.length ? f.lista.produtos.items.map(p => ({ 
            quantity: p?.quantity || null,
            value: p?.value || null
        }) : undefined, 
    },
}
```